# How to just print the chart from `mult.chart` in MSQC package for statistical process control

Tags: r, msqc

I am using `mult.chart` for SPC in an Rmarkdown file for a proof of concept. I just want to print the chart and leave out all the decompositions, xmv, covariance and t2.
when I use

```
t <- mult.chart(na.omit(test.data), type = "t2", Xmv = Xmv, S = S, colm = colm)
```

the object has everything but the chart.

```
> str(t)
List of 5
 $           : chr "Hotelling Control Chart"
 $ ucl       : num 13.8
 $ t2        : num [1:154, 1] 6.1 1.11 3.13 0.66 2.26 2.13 2.02 3.45 4.17 2.41 ...
 $ Xmv       : num [1:4] 130.9 94.8 957.4 490.1
 $ covariance: num [1:4, 1:4] 320 11 130 1000 11 0.87 4.9 32 130 4.9 ...
```

How can I extract the chart out of it?

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code of the function to add a ggplot chart to the output. I am posting the code below for everyone's benefit.

```
mult.chart2 <- function (type = c("chi", "t2", "mewma", "mcusum", 
                                  "mcusum2"), x, Xmv, S, colm, alpha = 0.01, lambda = 0.1, 
                         k = 0.5, h = 5.5, phase = 1, method = "sw", ...) 
{
    type <- match.arg(type)
    p <- ncol(x)
    m <- nrow(x)
    if (class(x) == "matrix" || class(x) == "data.frame") 
        (x <- array(data.matrix(x), c(m, p, 1)))
    n <- dim(x)[3]
    if (!missing(Xmv)) 
        (phase <- 2)
    x.jk <- matrix(0, m, p)
    t2 <- matrix(0, m, 1)
    x.jk <- apply(x, 1:2, mean)
    if (missing(Xmv)) 
        (Xmv <- colMeans(x.jk))
    if (missing(S)) 
        (S <- covariance(x, method = method))
    if (missing(colm)) 
        (colm <- nrow(x))
    if (type == "chi") {
        name <- paste("Chi-squared Control Chart")
        for (ii in 1:m) {
            t2[ii, 1] <- n * t(x.jk[ii, ] - Xmv) %*% solve(S) %*% 
                (x.jk[ii, ] - Xmv)
        }
        ucl <- qchisq(1 - alpha, p)
        if (any(t2 > ucl)) {
            cat("The following(s) point(s) fall outside the control limits")
            t3 <- which(t2 > ucl)
            print(t3)
        }
    }
    if (type == "t2") {
        name <- paste("Hotelling Control Chart")
        for (ii in 1:m) {
            t2[ii, 1] <- n * t(x.jk[ii, ] - Xmv) %*% solve(S) %*% 
                (x.jk[ii, ] - Xmv)
        }
        ifelse(n == 1, ifelse(phase == 1, ucl <- ((colm - 1)^2)/colm * 
                                  qbeta(1 - alpha, p/2, ((colm - p - 1)/2)), ucl <- ((p * 
                                                                                          (colm + 1) * (colm - 1))/((colm^2) - colm * p)) * 
                                  qf(1 - alpha, p, colm - p)), ifelse(phase == 1, ucl <- (p * 
                                                                                              (colm - 1) * (n - 1))/(colm * n - colm - p + 1) * 
                                                                          qf(1 - alpha, p, colm * n - colm - p + 1), ucl <- (p * 
                                                                                                                                 (colm + 1) * (n - 1))/(colm * n - colm - p + 1) * 
                                                                          qf(1 - alpha, p, colm * n - colm - p + 1)))
        if (any(t2 > ucl)) {
            cat("The following(s) point(s) fall outside of the control limits")
            t3 <- which(t2 > ucl)
            print(t3)
            for (ii in 1:length(t3)) {
                v = 1
                k = 0
                for (i in 1:p) {
                    k <- k + factorial(p)/(factorial(i) * factorial(p - 
                                                                        i))
                }
                q <- matrix(0, k, p + 3)
                for (i in 1:p) {
                    a <- t(combn(p, i))
                    for (l in 1:nrow(a)) {
                        for (j in 1:ncol(a)) {
                            q[v, j + 3] <- a[l, j]
                        }
                        v = v + 1
                    }
                }
                for (i in 1:nrow(q)) {
                    b <- subset(q[i, 4:ncol(q)], q[i, 4:ncol(q)] > 
                                    0)
                    di <- length(b)
                    if (length(b) > 1) {
                        q[i, 1] <- n * t(Xmv[b] - x.jk[t3[ii], ][b]) %*% 
                            solve(S[b, b]) %*% (Xmv[b] - x.jk[t3[ii], 
                            ][b])
                    }
                    else (q[i, 1] <- n * (x.jk[t3[ii], ][b] - Xmv[b])^2/S[b, 
                                                                          b])
                    ifelse(n == 1, ifelse(phase == 1, q[i, 2] <- ((colm - 
                                                                       1)^2)/colm * qbeta(1 - alpha, di/2, (((2 * 
                                                                                                                  (colm - 1)^2)/(3 * colm - 4) - di - 1)/2)), 
                                          q[i, 2] <- ((di * (colm + 1) * (colm - 1))/((colm^2) - 
                                                                                          colm * di)) * qf(1 - alpha, di, colm - 
                                                                                                               di)), ifelse(phase == 1, q[i, 2] <- (di * 
                                                                                                                                                        (colm - 1) * (n - 1))/(colm * n - colm - 
                                                                                                                                                                                   di + 1) * qf(1 - alpha, di, colm * n - colm - 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    di + 1), q[i, 2] <- (di * (colm + 1) * (n - 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                1))/(colm * n - colm - di + 1) * qf(1 - alpha, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    di, colm * n - colm - di + 1)))
                    q[i, 3] <- 1 - pf(q[i, 1], di, colm - 1)
                }
                colnames(q) <- c("t2 decomp", "ucl", 
                                 "p-value", 1:p)
                print(list(`Decomposition of` = t3[ii]))
                print(round(q, 4))
            }
        }
    }
    if (type == "mewma") {
        h4 <- matrix(c(8.6336, 9.6476, 10.083, 10.3114, 10.4405, 
                       10.5152, 10.5581, 10.5816, 10.5932, 10.814, 11.8961, 
                       12.3505, 12.5845, 12.7143, 12.788, 12.8297, 12.8524, 
                       12.8635, 12.7231, 13.8641, 14.3359, 14.576, 14.7077, 
                       14.7818, 14.8234, 14.846, 14.857, 14.5363, 15.7293, 
                       16.217, 16.4629, 16.5965, 16.6711, 16.7127, 16.7352, 
                       16.7463, 16.2634, 17.5038, 18.0063, 18.2578, 18.3935, 
                       18.4687, 18.5105, 18.5331, 18.5442, 17.9269, 19.2113, 
                       19.7276, 19.9845, 20.1223, 20.1982, 20.2403, 20.2631, 
                       20.2743, 19.541, 20.8665, 21.396, 21.6581, 21.798, 
                       21.8747, 21.9171, 21.9401, 21.9515, 21.1152, 22.4796, 
                       23.0217, 23.2887, 23.4307, 23.5082, 23.551, 23.5742, 
                       23.5858, 22.6565, 24.0579, 24.6119, 24.8838, 25.0278, 
                       25.1062, 25.1493, 25.1728, 25.1846), nrow = 9)
        rownames(h4) <- c(seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1))
        colnames(h4) <- c(1:9)
        z <- matrix(0, m, p)
        m1 <- rownames(h4)
        m2 <- colnames(h4)
        l <- lambda * 10
        ucl <- h4[m1[l], m2[p - 1]]
        name <- paste("MEWMA Control Chart")
        for (i in 1:m) {
            if (i == 1) {
                z[i, ] <- lambda * (x.jk[i, ] - Xmv)
            }
            else {
                z[i, ] <- lambda * (x.jk[i, ] - Xmv) + (1 - lambda) * 
                    z[i - 1, ]
            }
            weig <- S * (lambda * (1 - ((1 - lambda)^(2 * i)))/(2 - 
                                                                    lambda))
            t2[i, 1] <- t(z[i, ]) %*% solve(weig) %*% z[i, ]
        }
    }
    if (type == "mcusum") {
        name <- paste("MCUSUM Control Chart by Crosier (1988)")
        ucl <- h
        dif <- sweep(x.jk, 2, Xmv)
        s <- matrix(0, m, p)
        ci <- matrix(0, m, 1)
        ci[1] <- sqrt(dif[1, ] %*% solve((S/n)) %*% dif[1, ])
        if (ci[1] > k) {
            s[1, ] <- (s[1, ] + dif[1, ]) * (1 - k/ci[1])
        }
        else (s[1, ] = matrix(0, ncol = p))
        for (i in 2:m) {
            ci[i, ] = sqrt((s[i - 1, ] + dif[i, ]) %*% solve(S/n) %*% 
                               (s[i - 1, ] + dif[i, ]))
            if (ci[i] > k) {
                s[i, ] = (s[i - 1, ] + dif[i, ]) * (1 - k/ci[i])
            }
            else {
                s[i, ] = matrix(0, ncol = p)
            }
        }
        for (i in 1:m) {
            t2[i] = sqrt(s[i, ] %*% solve((S/n)) %*% (s[i, ]))
        }
    }
    if (type == "mcusum2") {
        name <- paste("MCUSUM Control Chart by Pignatiello (1990)")
        ucl <- h
        dif <- sweep(x.jk, 2, Xmv)
        s <- matrix(0, m, p)
        l <- matrix(0, m, 1)
        for (i in 1:m) {
            if (i == 1) {
                l[i, 1] <- 1
            }
            if (i > 1) {
                if (t2[i - 1, 1] > 0) {
                    l[i, 1] <- l[i - 1, 1] + 1
                }
                else {
                    l[i, 1] <- 1
                }
            }
            if (i == ((i - l[i, 1] + 1))) {
                s[i, ] <- dif[i, ]
            }
            else {
                s[i, ] <- colSums(dif[(i - l[i, 1] + 1):i, ])
            }
            t2[i, 1] <- max(0, (t(s[i, ]) %*% solve(S/n) %*% 
                                    s[i, ])^0.5 - k * l[i, 1])
        }
    }
    t3 <- which(t2 > ucl)
    # par(mar = c(4, 5, 3, 5))
    # plot(t2, ylim = c(0, 1.1 * max(max(t2), ucl)), main = name,
    #      xlab = "Sample", ylab = expression(T^2), type = "o",
    #      las = 1)
    # points(t3, t2[t3], col = 2)
    # segments(0, ucl, m, ucl, col = 2)
    # mtext(paste(" UCL=", round(ucl, 2)), side = 4, at = ucl,
    #       las = 2)
    
    t2df <- data.frame(t2) 
    t2df$oob <- ifelse(t2df$t2 > ucl, "bad", "good")
    t2df$sample <- seq(1:nrow(t2df))
    
    p2 <- ggplot(data = t2df) +
        geom_point(aes(x = sample, y = t2, color = oob)) + 
        scale_color_manual(values = c( "Red", "Grey20")) +
        geom_path(aes(x = sample, y = t2))+
        geom_hline(yintercept = ucl, color = "red") + 
        theme(legend.position = "none") 
        

    outList = list(
        name,
        ucl = round(ucl, 2),
        t2 = round(t2, 2),
        Xmv = round(Xmv, 2),
        covariance = signif(S, 2),
        plot2 = p2
    )
    return(outList)
}
```